# Refer to another Object inside own JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, object

I declare Homebrew as a dependency for cask and referred to homebrew by `this.homebrew[0]`. Is anything like this possible with JavaScript?

```
var data = {
  homebrew: [
    {
      title: "Homebrew",
      dependencies: [],
      install: function() {
         console.log('homebrew')
      }
    },
    {
      title: "Cask",
      dependencies: [
         this.homebrew[0]
      ],
      install: function() {
         console.log('cask')
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `data` should be an object in your case. Besides, how `dependencies` is used in further logic ?

Comment: `dependencies` should image the whole object titled `homebrew`

Comment: you can't do it in a single-step object literal - it's possible if you use multiple step initialisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using Javascript [***get***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) syntax(*defining a getter*):

```js
var data = {
  homebrew: [
    {
      title: "Homebrew",
      dependencies: [],
      install: function () {
        console.log('homebrew')
      }
    },
    {
      title: "Cask",
      get dependencies() {   //  <-- getter function
        return [data.homebrew[0]]
      },
      install: function () {
        console.log('cask')
      }
    }
  ]
};

console.log(data.homebrew[1].dependencies[0]);
```

Comment: I think this is an unsafe approach.  If the `homebrew` array gets rearranged the `dependencies` property will continue to return the zeroth item, breaking the dependency graph.

Comment: It also breaks one of my cardinal rules - that an object should never internally refer to itself by the name of the variable to which it has been assigned.

Comment: re: the latter comment, try `var x = data; data = {}; console.log(x.homebrew[1].dependencies)` - you now have a broken object

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. One thing you can do is create your objects outside of the array, and set up references that way, such as:

```
var Homebrew = { title: "Homebrew" }
var Cask = { title: "Cask", dependencies: [Homebrew] }
var data = [ Homebrew, Cask ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a separate dependency object.

```
var data = {
  homebrew: [
    {
      title: "Homebrew",
      dependencies: [],
      install: function() {
         console.log('homebrew')
      }
    },
    {
      title: "Cask",
      dependencies: [
         this.homebrew[0]
      ],
      install: function() {
         console.log('cask')
      }
    }
  ]
};

var dependencies = [
  {
    data.homebrew[0],
    data.homebrew[1]
  }
];
```